# Chrome App usb DigitalPersona fingerprinted reader not found

Tags: usb, google-chrome-app

I'm trying develop Google Chrome App(or extension, not sure) to use DigitalPersona fingerprint reader on Windows.

Following : 
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/usb

```
var DEVICE_INFO = {
    "vendorId": 1466, //0x05BA
    "productId": 10 //0x000A
};
chrome.usb.findDevices(DEVICE_INFO, call_method);
```

Result is "App was granted the 'usbDevices' permission, but device not found".
p.s. the usb information above was found in windows device manager.

Don't know why this happened.
Does Google Chrome not support DigitalPersona fingerprint reader?

p.s. Chrome://inspect said "No devices detected."

The content of manifest.json is the same as the example of knob, but vendorId and productId:

```
{
    "name": "USB Spinner Sample",
    "version": "0.3",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "minimum_chrome_version": "23",
    "app": {
        "background": {
            "scripts": ["background.js"]
        }
    },
    "permissions": ["usb"],
    "optional_permissions": [ {"usbDevices": [{"vendorId": 1466, "productId": 10}]}]
}
```

Comment: What's your manifest? Also, `chrome.usb` is only available in an app, so please edit out the extension tag.

Comment: Added the manifest.json

Comment: Do you really need that in `optional_permissions`? If yes, are you properly asking for them to be granted?

Comment: Another consideration, from the description of a [usb-label-printer sample app](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/usb-label-printer): _"Some Windows device drivers take ownership of the device and don't allow Chrome to connect to them. If `openDevice` or `findDevice` doesn't work for you, you can try to use a generic low level driver instead."_

Comment: After replacing driver with [Zadig](http://zadig.akeo.ie), this app found the device. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you manage to communicate with the finger print device after changing the driver? I can open the device using openDevice but it doesn't seems to pick up the finger scan event. Did you manage to capture finger print scan event using a generic driver ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted on the [usb-label-printer sample Chrome App](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/usb-label-printer):

> Some Windows device drivers take ownership of the device and don't allow Chrome to connect to them. If `openDevice` or `findDevice` doesn't work for you, you can try to use a generic low level driver instead.

This theory was confirmed by chiahao, as installing a generic low-level USB driver with the [Zadig](http://zadig.akeo.ie/) tool resolved the problem.

Comment: Did you manage to communicate with the DigitalPersona finger print scanner after changing it to a generic driver ? When I change the driver to a generic driver (libusbK), scanner blue light goes off. it doesn't seems to be working after that. I can open the device using openDevice but it doesn't seems to pick up the finger scan event. Please let me know how you did it. Thanks