# How chrome.usb.bulkTransfer read from DigitalPersona fingerprint reader?

Tags: usb, google-chrome-app

I tried to read fingerprint from the DigitalPersona fingerprint reader.

Followed the api [app_usb#bulk_transfers](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_usb#bulk_transfers), I wrote the code:

```
//ignore the findDevice() part

var transferInfo = {
    "direction": "in",
    "endpoint": 3, //don't know where to find device protocol, 3 is a random number.
    "length": 318
}
chrome.usb.bulkTransfer(connectionHandle, transferInfo, function(event){
    console.log("got " + event.data.byteLength + " bytes");
});
```

but my result is "got 0 bytes". Why?

Comment: to find the endpoint I use an USB explorer software (USBView in windows, USB prober in mac), it gives you some interesting data on the device, like the class where you could find a corresponding spec.

Comment: thanks for your answer. since i found the chrome can't get digitalPersona fingerprint reader without replace driver: [chrome-app-usb-digitalpersona-fingerprinted-reader-not-found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24377895/chrome-app-usb-digitalpersona-fingerprinted-reader-not-found), i'll give up developing on chrome.

Answer (score 1):

To get the correct endpoint, you should call the `chrome.usb.getConfiguration` function.

The result will be an object with a property called **interfaces**.

If you enumerate the interfaces found, you'll find for each one a property called **endpoints**, which enumerates the available ones.

Choose the endpoint according to the communication channel you want:

- in / out
- bulk / interrupt / ...

Then, fetch its **address** property to populate the `GenericTransferInfo` **endpoint** attribute for the `bulkTransfer` function call.

```
var transferInfo = {
    "direction": "in",
    "endpoint": 132, //value of "address" for the bulkTransfer/in endpoint
    "length": 318
}
```